# How to use firebase in DrawerNavigator and sync retrieve data

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-navigation-drawer

> **Objective**:

I want to retrieve the users `name` from **firebase** and then use in the **Text** component, but it returns before the data can be loaded from firebase, which causes the Text gets *undefined*.

> The Drawer code:

```js
export default Slidebar = (props) => {
  var name;

  firebase.database().ref('users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/profile').once("value")
  .then( (snapshot) => {
    name = (snapshot.val().name)
    console.log('snapshot name:', name)
  }) 

  return(
    <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor: "#121212"}}>
      <ImageBackground source={{uri: 'https://www.redebrasilatual.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/maconha-projeto.jpg'}} 
        style={{ padding: 16, paddingTop: 48 }} 
      >
        <Text style={styles.name}> { name, console.log('text name: ', name) } </Text>        
        <Text style={styles.email}>email@example.com</Text>


        <TouchableOpacity style={{height: 40, width: 40}} onPress={() => console.log(name)} >
          <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white'}} />
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </ImageBackground>

      <View style={styles.container}>
          <DrawerNavigatorItems {...props} />
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
```

> The console output:

`INFO
17:06
text name:  undefined
INFO
17:06
snapshot name: Joao Pedro`

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
i already tried `useState` before, but i think i did something wrong, but now its working well!

```js
const [name, setName] = useState("teste");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("email");

  firebase.database().ref('users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/profile').once("value")
  .then( (snapshot) => {
    setName(snapshot.val().name)
    setEmail(snapshot.val().email)
  })
```